# Action listener not updating variable in java

Tags: java, swing

I am working on creating a small program to recreate a game. So far I have created a small GUI. My question is when I created an action listener to update the variable counterNum which then updates cookieCountLabel the screen does not update it only says one. I thought that if the button is clicked counterNum should equal counterNum + 1. And then it should have updated cookieCountLabel, but this didn't seem to work.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
/**
 *Author:Graham
 *Lang:Java
 *Program: Cookie Clicker
 *Date Created: 6/22/2019
 *CITATION:
 *Some GUI concepts from(the pdf you provided):https://lms.dist113.org/attachment/907907595/docviewer
 *Some GUI concepts from https://www.guru99.com/java-swing-gui.html
 */
public class Clicker extends JComponent
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //variables



        //frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cookie Clicker");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setSize(300,300);

        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        //close on click x
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //buttons
        JButton cookie = new JButton("Cookie");
        cookie.setBounds(80,0, 140, 20);
        //to set visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(cookie);



        //listen for click
        cookie.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Integer counterNum = 0;
            counterNum += 1;
            String convert = counterNum.toString();
            JLabel cookieCountLabel = new JLabel();
            cookieCountLabel.setBounds(140,120,50,20);
            cookieCountLabel.setText(convert);
            frame.add(cookieCountLabel);



            }



        });


    }
}
```

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Are you sure you want to add a new Label every time the button is clicked? And as you are using a null-layout, I'm not sure where those additional labels will be placed and if they are thus visible at all.

Comment: @cello's comment brought me on the right track... with every click, you create a new label. The label's text is initiailzed through local variable `counterNum`, which is initialized with `0` and then incremented to `1`. Thus you create labels over and over again, all showing `1`.

Comment: oh is there a way I can make it so a new label is not created?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are setting your counterNum to 0 every time you click the button. Therefore, your counterNum value will always show as 1:

```
cookie.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Integer counterNum = 0; !!! -> error here
            counterNum += 1;
```

To fix this, take out your counterNum variable out of the main method and make it a field.

```
public class Clicker extends JComponent
{
    private static int counterNum; !!!

    public static void main(String[] args){
     ...
```

Next, every time you press the button, you create a new Label which holds the value of the counterNum. As suggested in the comments, you probably don't want to create a new Label object every time you press the button, but rather you want to change the value that is written on the Label. Therefore, take out your Label creation code from the ActionListener and put it in your main method. Now you will only have 1 Label that holds the value of counterNum.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        JLabel cookieCountLabel = new JLabel(); !!!
        cookieCountLabel.setBounds(140,120,50,20); !!!

        //frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cookie Clicker");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Now, whenever you press the button, no new Label is created, but the value of counterNum is changed and incremented by 1. This is how your ActionListener should look like now:

```
cookie.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        counterNum += 1; //increment counterNum by 1
        String convert = counterNum + ""; //convert to String
        cookieCountLabel.setText(convert);
        frame.add(cookieCountLabel);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @tom if the answer has resolved your problem, can you please mark the answer as accepted by pressing on the tick on the left hand side. Thank you!